# Origen de puente como sinónimo de feriado

Tags: etimología, historia

De acuerdo con la 6.<sup>a</sup> acepción de '[**puente**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UZtOEos)', se toma como una sucesión de feriados utilizados para vacaciones.

Este término, aparece en el mapa de diccionarios *recientemente* (en 1992) y en 1925 aparece la frase "***hacer puente***" donde se toma como feriado un día que no lo es pero está situado entre dos (que parece ser la frase de origen con un tinte metafórico).

¿Desde qué época se utiliza el término 'puente' con este sentido? ¿Viene desde la frase "*hacer puente*" el posterior "***día puente***" (2 o más festivos consecutivos) para el actual 'puente'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No he podido encontrar alguna referencia académica o en diccionarios sobre el origen de esta peculiar expresión en español. Pero yo sospecho que es de origen francés.

En francés también existe la expresión *Faire le pont*, literalmente "hacer puente".

El [Diccionario de la Academia Francesa](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-dictionnaire/la-9e-edition) detalla el significado de esta expresión [en la entrada para la palabra *pont*](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/pont?page=1) (puente):

> *Faire le pont*, ne pas travailler durant les jours ouvrés séparant deux jours fériés

(Español: *hacer el puente*: no trabajar durante los días hábiles que separan a dos días feriados.)

Según el [TLFi](http://atilf.atilf.fr/), e**l registro de autoridad más antiguo de esta expresión en francés es de 1867**, en el *Dictionnaire de la Langue Verte* de Alfred Delvau:

> **c)** **1867** «congé que s'accorde un employé pour joindre deux autres congés qui lui ont été accordés» (Delvau); **1867** faire le pont (ibid.).

(Español:  «días de descanso que se conceden a un empleado para unir dos otros días de descanso que le habían sido concedidos».)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero para sumarte el punto extra... ¿Podrías  traducir los significados del francés? El nivel de francés mío (y de más de uno) suele ser (muy) básico. De antemano, *merci*...

Comment: @VeAqui perdona, compañero. Ya pongo las traducciones.